# Combine three variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to change the filename of a jpg that gets uploaded, then rename it based on the following, but it doesn't work.

```
$myfile = ( $_FILES['image']['name']);
$myfile = str_replace("'", '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('&', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('%', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('!', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('#', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace(' ', '', $myfile);

$random = mt_rand(22, 32);
$cj = "cj-";
$myfile = $cj . $random . $myfile;
```

If I comment out the very last line it works so the combining of the 3 variables appears to be the problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: what's the issue? does it crash, become an empty string, nothing gets printed? define "problem"

Comment: It looks perfect to me..

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.  The script just fails and the page is blank.  If I comment out the last line where I combine the variables it works, otherwise I just get a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your code

Since I couldn't find anything I decided to try the code myself to see what is the output

This is the code I used:

```
<?php
$myfile = "#'&!#  Some_file";
$myfile = str_replace("'", '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('&', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('%', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('!', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace('#', '', $myfile);
$myfile = str_replace(' ', '', $myfile);

$random = mt_rand(22, 32);
$cj = "cj-";
$final_file_name = $cj . $random . $myfile;

echo 'Random: '.$random."\n";
echo 'Cj: '.$cj."\n";
echo 'MyFile: '.$myfile."\n";
echo 'Final name: '.$final_file_name."\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Random: 25
Cj: cj-
MyFile: Some_file
Final name: cj-25Some_file
```

Basically, it is working perfectly. Nothing is wrong.

Demo: [Here](http://codepad.org/iwK84QlF)

Since we can't find out what is wrong and why your code isn't working we'll try a different apporach

```
$random = mt_rand(22,32);
$cj = 'cj-';
$final_file_name = $cj;
$final_file_name .= $random;
$final_file_name .= $myfile;
```

Comment: Interesting, it does not work for me as long as I combine the variables.  If I leave that out, it works.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Full code is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E75w7Gc-7cT0Xytkrwc9Rh-e4F2fqt7mbvwaU1iblII/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I can't really seem to find anything and I can't understand why it isn't working but I'll add in my answer a different approach that you might wanna try.

Comment: Added the different approach. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks!  Um...where is it? I don't see a link anywhere.  Sorry, found it.

Comment: It's the part under the demo, the code part.. Add it to your code and tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work.  I'm wondering if it's some weird encoding issue or something.  The code I had should have worked.

Comment: It turns out the code worked, but I had another issue further down the script.  It took me several hours to find it and I had to re-do the code.  Thanks for all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myfile = $cj . strval($random) . $myfile;
```

Comment: $random gets converted to string anyway, don't need to use thta function.

Answer (score 0):

In my example here, I'm checking to see if the file exists (the only thing I can think of as a failure). The blank screen is a parser error (usually something related to syntax). I've also shortened the code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
   $myfile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $patterns = array("'","&","%","!","#"," ");
   $myfile = "cj-".mt_rand(22, 32).str_replace($patterns, '', $myfile);
   echo $myfile;
} else {
   echo "Empty Filename.";
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm uploading an image so the image won't exist yet. Sorry, I'm not so good at PHP syntax.  If you look at my code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E75w7Gc-7cT0Xytkrwc9Rh-e4F2fqt7mbvwaU1iblII/edit?usp=sharing) I think it has to do with a line further down where $pic = $myfile.  That's where it chokes.  Thanks!